# Corona Lua - Facebook Post Video

Tags: iphone, facebook, lua, coronasdk

I am using Corona and have integrated my app to share a message and photo using FB Graph Api. Does anyone know how to post video in Corona.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ there are no write permission on Facebook for uploading video.

You can use facebook.request( "me/photos", "POST", attachment ) to post photos, but there are no "me/video" or anything similar, mostly because Facebook do not want it for some reason of their own.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I know it is possible to post a video to a users facebook wall as i can do this in iOS. There is also an example for this by Christine Abernathy. http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/

Comment: So my next problem is more to do i guess with syntax. In order for me to create a request as a "video file attachment as multipart/form-data " i have to convert my video as MIME which is easily done with iOS using NSData. However, in corona i found: http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/how-upload-image-server-multipartform-data....But still cannot seem to figure it out ... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/ mentions two How-Tos:

- [How to upload a video to a user's profile using Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/): *“To publish a video, issue a POST request with the video file attachment as multipart/form-data to `https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos`”*
- [How to upload a video to an Application, Group, or Page's wall using Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/515/#video_upload)